# Making a LaTeX version of System Usability Scale table

Tags: tables

I'm trying to create a LaTeX version of the [System Usability Scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_usability_scale) that rather faithfully reproduces the original. It roughly resembles a table, but is a rather specialized version of one.

[image: Excerpt from System Usability Scale questionnaire]

My rather naive attempt where I lose the correct spacing

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{L{0.5\textwidth}|C{0.1\textwidth}|C{0.1\textwidth}|C{0.1\textwidth}|C{0.1\textwidth}|C{0.1\textwidth}|}
\cline{2-6}
I think that I would like to use this system frequently                                   & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \cline{2-6} 
I found the system unnecessarily complex                                                  & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \cline{2-6} 
I thought the system was easy to use                                                      & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \cline{2-6} 
I think that I would need the support of a technical person to be able to use this system & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \cline{2-6} 
I found the various functions in this system were well integrated                         & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \cline{2-6} 
I thought there was too much inconsistency in this system                                 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \cline{2-6} 
I would imagine that most people would learn to use this system very quickly              & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \cline{2-6} 
I found the system very cumbersome to use                                                 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \cline{2-6} 
I felt very confident using the system                                                    & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \cline{2-6} 
I needed to learn a lot of things before I could get going with this system               & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\ \cline{2-6} 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I would like to know if achieving this style should be using 100% tables or if there is a trick to keep the right-hand rows wrapping the numbers? I'd like to avoid using images.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could do something like the following, I suppose. It combines the enumerate environment with a tabular.  (Below is an edited version, which contains the new command `\printtblhdr`, which is now used following a `\section`.)

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist[enumerate,1]{labelindent=0pt, leftmargin=*}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}

\newcolumntype{P}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{0.75cm}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{0.2\textwidth}}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}m{0.2\textwidth}}

\newcommand{\printtblhdr}{%
  \hfill
  \begingroup
  \setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}%
  \begin{tabularx}{0.41\textwidth}{ @{} l *{3}X r @{} }
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\bfseries\shortstack[l]{Strongly\\ Disagree}}
    &&
    \multicolumn{2}{l}{\bfseries\shortstack[r]{Strongly\\ Agree}}
    \\
  \end{tabularx}
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\usetbl}{%
  \begin{tabular}{@{}|*5{P|}@{}}
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
}

\newcommand\prop[1]{%
  \item
  \parbox[t]{0.5\textwidth}{#1}%
  \qquad
  \parbox[t]{0.5\textwidth}{\usetbl}%
}


\begin{document}

\section{Your Views Are Important to Us}


\printtblhdr

\begin{enumerate}
\prop{I think that I would like to use this system frequently}

\prop{I found the system unnecessarily complex}

\prop{I thought the system was easy to use}

\prop{I think that I would need the support of a technical person to be able to use this system}

\prop{I found the various functions in this system were well integrated}

\prop{I thought there was too much inconsistency in this system}

\prop{I would imagine that most people would learn to use this system very quickly}

\prop{I found the system very cumbersome to use}

\prop{I felt very confident using the system}

\prop{I needed to learn a lot of things before I could get going with this system}

\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow. That is very nice.

Comment: If I put the questionnaire below a \section header it causes the header Strong disagree/agree to shift a bit to the left. Why is that?

Comment: @CameronLowellPalmer -- well, I think it's because the first version was a little lazy in its implementation. This is a little more rigorous.  Hopefully, you find that it works better.

Answer (score 6):

A style with automatic numbering and automatic placing of a `scaletable`

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{array}

\newcounter{rowcntr}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{N}[1]{>{\stepcounter{rowcntr}\therowcntr.}R{#1}}




\newcommand{\scaletable}{%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{|*{5}{c|}}%
    \hline
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \tabularnewline
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
}



\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\begin{tabular}{N{1cm}L{0.6\textwidth}C{0.3\textwidth}}
\multicolumn{1}{l}{}  & &     \footnotesize \bfseries\parbox{0.14\textwidth}{Strongly\\ disagree}\parbox{0.14\textwidth}{\raggedleft Strongly agree} \tabularnewline
&I think that I would like to use this system frequently                                   & \scaletable \tabularnewline
&I found the system unnecessarily complex                                                  & \scaletable \tabularnewline
&I thought the system was easy to use                                                      & \scaletable \tabularnewline
&I think that I would need the support of a technical person to be able to use this system & \scaletable \tabularnewline
&I found the various functions in this system were well integrated                         & \scaletable \tabularnewline
&I thought there was too much inconsistency in this system                                 & \scaletable \tabularnewline
&I would imagine that most people would learn to use this system very quickly              & \scaletable \tabularnewline
&I found the system very cumbersome to use                                                 & \scaletable \tabularnewline
&I felt very confident using the system                                                    & \scaletable \tabularnewline
&I needed to learn a lot of things before I could get going with this system               & \scaletable \tabularnewline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can define the whole tabular with numbers 1--5 and vertical and horizontal lines as a macro (nearly as in your example). Then it remains to define tabular as follows

```
\begin{tabular}{L{0.5\textwidth}@{\YourEarlierDefinedMacro}}
```

In this case `@` defines element which appears in every verse.

Comment: I like this macro idea although I must figure out how to create a table in a macro.